# PHP: Convert PDF content to readable text?

Tags: php, pdf

How do I convert this PDF content into readable text using PHP?

Only the start of the PDF content is pasted in here:

```
%PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj [/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text] endobj 3 0 obj <>/XObject<>>>/Length 9 0 R /Filter/FlateDecode>> stream x��X�nGm��h��^��-�P�v�{���fmcl|�hߒ)R�/I� �Ӝ���7��Gk�mwU��:u����d2���ϣ�NG[od�V��G�8Yǝs��ZsN�`5�e�����/#ey�H�g����7"�Ӗ��{� |����f��9޻�0H�,aUV�����w�����*�`�t8V\��O8��]@�oP?!�'K?ǩ��=>NQղ�kH���N�g3��u�![fc���{��� Y����n���X8��7d]���� �O�at+;�^dKl1�v�0�;��ʴ�ֺ���/?�>���u�'��Җ�;�D
```

Comment: There are many libraries that can read and extract information from a PDF file. You should use one of them.

Comment: How do you get this content?

Comment: Hi Dekel :-) Yes, but I did not get any to work. Which one would work?

Hi Rishi :-) It is from www.e-conomic.com where we pull out the PDF content from our accounting system.